# computation involving independent increments

Tags: brownian-motion

One can rather easily show that E[$\sum_{i = 0}^{i = n - 1}W_{t_i}(W_{t_{i + 1}} - W_{t_i})]$ = -T + $W_T^2$.

What I'm confused about is why we can't simply say that for each i, $W_{t_{i}}$ is independent of $(W_{t_{i + 1}} - W_{t_i})$, so that upon interchanging sums and expectations, and using independence we have E[$\sum_{i = 0}^{i = n - 1}W_{t_i}(W_{t_{i + 1}} - W_{t_i})]$ = $\sum_{i = 0}^{i = n - 1}E[W_{t_{i}}]E[W_{t_{i + 1}} - W_{t_i}]$ = 0?

In this problem, we have naturally partitioned an interval as $0 = t_{0} < t_{1} < ... < t_{n} = T$, and $W_{t}$ is a Brownian motion.

Comment: Question closed. Answer provided on math.stackexchange is sufficient.

Comment: Where on math.stackexchange can we find the answer? The question as posted here must be wrong as in the first line you have an ordinary expectation (thus a real number) on the lhs and a random variable on the rhs.

Comment: The question is cross-posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159240/brownian-motion-independent-increment-computation user7348: please mind your manners and stop cross posting questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's cross-posted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159240/brownian-motion-independent-increment-computation

Answer (score 0):

$W_{t_i}$ and $W_{t_i}$ are not independent (in fact $W_{t_i}=W_{t_i}$), e.g.
$$E[W_t^2]=t^2\neq E[W_t]\cdot E[W_t]=0$$
So you cant separate the expectation in your equation.

Comment: My comment said the question is closed, and I didn't want any additional answers.Furthermore, you're wrong. ($W_{t_{i}} - W_{t_{0}})(W_{t_{i + 1}} - W_{t_{i}})$ can be split because the increments are independent by definition of Brownian Motion.

Comment: @user7348 I don't understand your comments, and the increments you quote are not same as in the question.